# Repeat loop with if conditions for first and last time

Tags: loops, for-loop, applescript

I have a script that I made that works fine but I have to make some very minor edits to the output. Instead I'd like to just do it correctly.

```
on run {input, parameters}
set the formatted to {}
set listContents to get the clipboard
set delimitedList to paragraphs of listContents
repeat with listitem in delimitedList
    set myVar to "@\"" & listitem & "\"," & (ASCII character 10)
    copy myVar to the end of formatted
end repeat
display dialog formatted as string
return formatted as string
end run
```

I'd like prepend the first item slightly differently and append the last a little different.

I tried the following but the script is not right.

```
repeat with n from 1 to count of delimitedList
  -- not sure how to if/else n == 0 or delimitedList.count
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more efficient way, `text item delimiters`. It can insert the comma and the linefeed character between the list items

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set the formatted to {}
    set listContents to get the clipboard
    set delimitedList to paragraphs of listContents
    repeat with listitem in delimitedList
        copy "@" & quote & listitem & quote to the end of formatted
    end repeat
    set {saveTID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {"," & linefeed}}
    set formatted to formatted as text
    set text item delimiters to saveTID
    display dialog formatted
    return formatted
end run
```

Side note: `ASCII character 10` is deprecated since macOS 10.5 Leopard, there is `linefeed`, `tab` (9), `return` (13), `space` (32) and `quote` (34).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to an index or range, the various items of a list can also be accessed by using location parameters such as `first`, `last`, `beginning`, etc (note that AppleScript lists start at index 1).  To deal with the first and last items separately, you can do something like:

```
on run {input, parameters} -- example
   set formatted to {}
   set delimitedList to paragraphs of (the clipboard)
   if delimitedList is not {} then
      if (count delimitedList) > 2 then repeat with anItem in items 2 thru -2 of delimitedList
         set the end of formatted to "@" & quote & anItem & quote
      end repeat
      set the beginning of formatted to "@" & quote & "First: " & first item of delimitedList & quote -- or whatever
      if rest of delimitedList is not {} then set the end of formatted to "@" & quote & "Last: " & last item of delimitedList & quote -- or whatever
      set {tempTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "," & linefeed}
      set {formatted, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {formatted as text, tempTID}
   end if
   display dialog formatted as text
   return formatted as text
end run
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I used the first result but will investigate this one also